# ¿Como guardar un Excel creado en C# en un directorio especifico?

Tags: c#, excel

estoy intentando guardar un excel que se crea con los datos en una lista, pero no me lo guarda. Tambien quisiera saber como hacer para darle un nombre especifico a ese Excel, por ejemplo,que se llame `"Respaldo " + Dia/Mes/Año` y como hacer para que el archivo que se genere sea `.xlsx` y no `.xls`.

Les dejo el codigo que estoy utilizando:

```
private void btn_exportar_excel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string ruta = "c:\\Respaldo";
            SaveFileDialog fichero = new SaveFileDialog();
            fichero.Filter = "Excel (*.xls)|*.xls";
            IList<DTO_Inscripcion> inscripciones = svInscripcion.getInscripciones();
            if (!Directory.Exists("c:\\Respaldo"))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory("c:\\Respaldo");

                //Valido que la lista tenga valores para guardar
                if (inscripciones != null && inscripciones.Count > 0)
                {
                    // este try es para capturar algun error que pueda suceder al momento de crear y dar formato al Excel
                    try
                    {
                        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application aplicacion;
                        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook libros_trabajo;
                        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet hoja_trabajo;
                        aplicacion = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
                        libros_trabajo = aplicacion.Workbooks.Add();
                        hoja_trabajo =
                            (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)libros_trabajo.Worksheets.get_Item(1);

                        for (int i = 0; i < dgv_inscripciones.Rows.Count; i++)
                        {
                            for (int j = 0; j < dgv_inscripciones.Columns.Count; j++)
                            {
                                hoja_trabajo.Cells[i + 2, j + 1] = dgv_inscripciones.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value.ToString();
                            }
                        }
                        hoja_trabajo.Cells[1, "A"] = "Socio";
                        hoja_trabajo.Cells[1, "B"] = "Nombre";
                        hoja_trabajo.Cells[1, "C"] = "Apellido";
                        hoja_trabajo.Cells[1, "D"] = "Vencimiento";
                        hoja_trabajo.Cells[1, "E"] = "Estado";
                        hoja_trabajo.Cells[1, "F"] = "Fecha Pago";

                        //hoja_trabajo.Range["A5", "F5"].Merge();
                        hoja_trabajo.Range["A1", "F" + dgv_inscripciones.Rows.Count.ToString()].HorizontalAlignment = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlHAlign.xlHAlignCenter;
                        hoja_trabajo.Range["A1", "F" + dgv_inscripciones.Rows.Count.ToString()].Font.Bold = true;
                        hoja_trabajo.Range["A1", "F" + dgv_inscripciones.Rows.Count.ToString()].Font.Size = 20;

                        //este try es para capturar algun error al momento de intentar guardar el archivo
                        try
                        {
                            libros_trabajo.SaveAs(ruta, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal);
                            libros_trabajo.Close(true);
                            aplicacion.Quit();
                        }
                        catch(Exception exsave)
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show("Error al intentar guardar el archivo", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                        }
                    }
                    catch(Exception ex)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Error al intentar generar el archivo Excel", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                    }

                    
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("No hay datos para guardar", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                }
            }
}
```

Cuando ejecuto el codigo me salta la siguiente excepcion y la captura el primer Catch:

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: 'Microsoft Excel no puede obtener acceso al archivo 'c:\'. Puede haber varios motivos:

• El nombre o la ruta del archivo no existen.
• Otro programa está usando el archivo.
• El libro que está intentando guardar tiene el mismo nombre que otro libro que está abierto en estos momentos.'
```

Comment: Saca los message box, y fijate cual es el error especifico que esta ocurriendo.. un message box que solo dice ocurrio un error no ayuda para nada

Comment: Si, no me di cuenta, ya agregue la excepción que salta.

Comment: el error es claro.. ruta no es un archivo valido.. sera eso???

Comment: No entiendo muy bien como trabaja con el tema de excel, pero fíjate que el primer if valida que la ruta exista y si no existe la crea. Cuando voy al disco C a revisar, la carpeta esta creada pero no entiendo bien porque no puede leer la ruta.

Comment: Porque te esta pidiendo un nombre de archivo con la ruta.. si le pasas una ruta sola, entonces como esperas que llame al archivo?

Comment: Ahhhh ya entendí como funciona, ya lo soluciones, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tu código tiene varios detalles que habrá que resolver para que funcione correctamente y logre lo que deseas, intentaré dar solución a los aspectos que he podido detectar.

Ante todo, en el primer `if`, verificas que la ruta no existe y a continuación la creas, pero todo el procedimiento de exportación está dentro del bloque `if`, de tal forma que si la ruta existe, no se realizará exportación alguna, el procedimiento de exportación debes sacarlo del bloque `if`.

Coloco a continuación el código corregido y comentado.

```
               private void btn_exportar_excel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
                                    {
                                        string ruta = "c:\\Respaldo";
                                        SaveFileDialog fichero = new SaveFileDialog();
                                        fichero.Filter = "Excel (*.xls)|*.xls";
                                        IList<DTO_Inscripcion> inscripciones = svInscripcion.getInscripciones();
            //Verficas si el suddirectorio no existe y si no existe se crea
                                        if (!Directory.Exists("c:\\Respaldo"))
                                        {
            //Todo el código siguiente fuera del bloque if, para que se ejecute siempre
        Directory.CreateDirectory("c:\\Respaldo");
                                        }
                                        
            //Valido que la lista tenga valores para guardar
                                        if (inscripciones != null && inscripciones.Count > 0)
                                        {
                                           // este try es para capturar algun error que pueda suceder al momento de crear y dar formato al Excel
                                             try
                                             {
                                         Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application aplicacion;
                                                    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook libros_trabajo;
                                                    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet hoja_trabajo;
                                                    aplicacion = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
                                                    libros_trabajo = aplicacion.Workbooks.Add();
                                                    hoja_trabajo =
                                                        (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)libros_trabajo.Worksheets.get_Item(1);
                            
                                                    for (int i = 0; i < dgv_inscripciones.Rows.Count; i++)
                                                    {
                                                        for (int j = 0; j < dgv_inscripciones.Columns.Count; j++)
                                                        {
                                                            hoja_trabajo.Cells[i + 2, j + 1] = dgv_inscripciones.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value.ToString();
                                                        }
                                                    }
                                                    hoja_trabajo.Cells[1, "A"] = "Socio";
                                                    hoja_trabajo.Cells[1, "B"] = "Nombre";
                                                    hoja_trabajo.Cells[1, "C"] = "Apellido";
                                                    hoja_trabajo.Cells[1, "D"] = "Vencimiento";
                                                    hoja_trabajo.Cells[1, "E"] = "Estado";
                                                    hoja_trabajo.Cells[1, "F"] = "Fecha Pago";
                            
                                                    //hoja_trabajo.Range["A5", "F5"].Merge();
                                                    hoja_trabajo.Range["A1", "F" + dgv_inscripciones.Rows.Count.ToString()].HorizontalAlignment = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlHAlign.xlHAlignCenter;
                                                    hoja_trabajo.Range["A1", "F" + dgv_inscripciones.Rows.Count.ToString()].Font.Bold = true;
                                                    hoja_trabajo.Range["A1", "F" + dgv_inscripciones.Rows.Count.ToString()].Font.Size = 20;
                            
                                                    //este try es para capturar algun error al momento de intentar guardar el archivo
                                                    try
                                                    {
            //Antes de guardar hay que completar la ruta con el nombre del archivo
            //Creamos el nombre del archivo agregando "Respaldo " + Dia-Mes-Año
            //El nombre que pedias "Respaldo " + Dia/Mes/Año no es valido pues el caracter / no es aceptado.
            
            DateTime hoy = DateTime.Now;
            string nbreArchivo = "Respaldo " + hoy.Day + "-" + hoy.Month + "-" + hoy.Year;
            
            //Concatenamos la ruta.
            string rutaCompleta =ruta +"\"+nbreArchivo;//Con esta ruta es que guarderemos el archivo

//libros_trabajo.SaveAs(ruta, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal);

//Para guardar con formato xlsx cambia la linea anterior por la siguiente y usando además rutaCompleta. 
    
    libros_trabajo.SaveAs(rutaCompleta , Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFileFormat.xlOpenXMLWorkbook);
            libros_trabajo.Close(true);
                                                        aplicacion.Quit();
                                                    }
                                                    catch(Exception exsave)
                                                    {
                                                        MessageBox.Show("Error al intentar guardar el archivo", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                                                    }
                                                }
                                                catch(Exception ex)
                                                {
                                                    MessageBox.Show("Error al intentar generar el archivo Excel", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                                                }
                            
                                                
                                            }
                                            else
                                            {
                                                MessageBox.Show("No hay datos para guardar", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                                            }
                            }
```